# Why java.lang.StackOverflowError: null when I try to print my entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm new in spring and I have a problem with my mapping classes.
When I want to to string a collection i have a strange error like StackOverflowError: null

This is my first entity.

```
@Entity(name = "utilisateurs")
public class Utilisateur {
@Id @GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id_utilisateur")
private Integer id;
@Pattern(regexp = "[\\p{L} '-]+",message = "ce champ ne doit pas contenir des 
chiffres")
@NotNull
@Column(name = "nom")
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_utilisateur")
private List<Reservation> reservations= new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Utilisateur{" +
            "id=" + id +

            ", reservations=" + reservations +
            '}';
    }
```

This is my second class Terrains

```
@Entity(name = "terrains")
public class Terrain {

@Id @GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id_terrain")
private Integer id;


@NotNull
@Size(min = 3, max = 25)
@Column(name = "nom_terrain")
@TerrainUnique(message = "terrain deja existant")
private  String nomTerrain;

@Column(name = "actif")
private  boolean actif;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_utilisateur")
private Utilisateur utilisateur;
```

And i have my third class also reservations

```
@Id @GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
@Column(name = "date_creation_reservation")
 @ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_utilisateur")
private   Utilisateur utilisateur;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_terrain")
private Terrain terrain;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_tarif")
private Tarif tarif;
  @Override
public String toString() {
    return "Reservation{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", dateCreationReservation=" + dateCreationReservation +
            ", dateReservation=" + dateReservation +
            ", heureDebut=" + heureDebut +
            ", heureFin=" + heureFin +
            ", actif=" + actif +
            ", optional=" + optional +
            ", utilisateur=" + utilisateur +
            ", terrain=" + terrain +
            ", tarif=" + tarif +
            '}';
             }
```

The error comes when I try to print my List

When a try to show this list in my controller  hier is my code:

```
  @GetMapping("/liste")
   public String showTerrains(Model model){

    //is like terrainsRepository.findAll()
    terrains=metierTerrain.showTerrain();
    System.out.println("voici la liste des terrains"+terrains);

  //  System.out.println( "voici la personne qui a ajouté le 
    terrain"+terrain.getUtilisateur() );
    model.addAttribute("terrains", terrains);


    return "terrains/listeTerrains";
}
```

I'm sur the error come from this mapping  in the Terrain Class but don't know why  and how i can to repair this

```
@Entity(name = "terrains")
public class Terrain {
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_utilisateur")
private Utilisateur utilisateur;}
```

Hier you can see a image with my error
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLVby.jpg)

An hier is a image with my database 
[data base eer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GhAx.png)

I will really appreciated if you can give me a solution for my problem
Thank you in advance

Comment: `Utilisateur` and  `reservations` call each other in the `toString()` method which causes an endless loop which results in an stackoverflow

Comment: Only include the to-one reference in your toString()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `StackOverflowError` is because you are(implicitely) calling `Utilisateur#toString` from `Terrain#toString` that call `Utilisateur#toString` that call `Terrain#toString` that call `Utilisateur#toString` that call `Terrain#toString` ...

**Edit**; It is not `Terrain` but `Reservation` as said in the comment below.

Comment: Besides the fact that we don't know the `Terrain#toString` and we can surely tell that the loop is between `Utilisateur` and `reservations` this is about right

Comment: Yes sorry, I mixed `Terrain` and `Reservation`. The screenshot of the error show the faulty classes.

Comment: so the problem is between reservation and utilisateur? Not between terrain and Utilisateur? Because the problem is appeard whene I map the Terrains with Utilisateur `@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_utilisateur")
private Utilisateur utilisateur;}`

Comment: Because I need to print also the collection of reservation for every utilisateur?

Comment: If you need to display the reservations from the `toString` method in `Utilisateur` then you have to print them yourself without using `Reservation#toString`. Note that `Object#toString` is not there to display to user but more for debugging.